# What's the difference between these two codes?

Tags: python, extend, shallow-copy

I recently started coding in Python 2.7. I'm a molecular biologist.
I'm writing a script that involves creating lists like this one:

```
mylist = [[0, 4, 6, 1], 102]
```

These lists are incremented by adding an item to mylist[0] and summing a value to mylist[1].

To do this, I use the code:

```
def addres(oldpep, res):
    return [oldpep[0] + res[0], oldpep[1] + res[1]]
```

Which works well. Since mylist[0] can become a bit long, and I have millions of these lists to take care of, I thought that using append or extend might make my code faster, so I tried:

```
def addres(pep, res):
    pep[0].extend(res[0])
    pep[1] += res[1]
    return pep
```

Which in my mind should give the same result.  It *does* give the same result when I try it on an arbitrary list. But when I feed it to the million of lists, it gives me a very different result.  So... what's the difference between the two? All the rest of the script is exactly the same.
Thank you!
Roberto

Comment: What reason did you have to believe that using append or extend might make your code faster? What part of things were you trying to improve?

Comment: I noticed in a couple of other scripts that if a is a very long list, then the code a = a + [b] is much slower than a.append(b) ... Am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @Roberto You're right. The reason, though, is exactly because of the copying behavior that's breaking your code. The difference is that `a.append(b)` modifies the list `a` to have an extra element, where `a += [b]` creates a new list containing the contents of `a` followed by the element `b`, and then assigns it to the name `a`. If nobody else is using the list that used to be called `a`, it's then thrown away, for the same net effect. The problem is that in your code, apparently, someone else is still using the old list by that name.

Comment: a = a + [b] is creating a new list containing one element (b), then combining the two lists together into another new list; a.append(b) is just adding a new item to the existing list a -- so the second operation is faster because it's doing significantly less work.

Comment: @Roberto: But even with lists of tens of millions of values, all those appends add up to milliseconds, and in most programs that's unlikely to be anywhere near a bottleneck. It's always important to figure out what's making your code slow and speed up _that_ part, not to just pick something arbitrary and speed it up.

Comment: @Dougal: thank you! That's what I thought!

Comment: @abarnert: My scripts so far aren't very long, but I do try to identify where they're slowing. I'm studying the basics too, to leave tinkering behind and start doing things properly. Thanks!

Comment: @MaxFellows: yes, that's what I noticed! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the second version of `addres` *modifies* the list that you passed in as `pep`, where the first version returns a new one.

```
>>> mylist = [[0, 4, 6, 1], 102]
>>> list2 = [[3, 1, 2], 205]
>>> addres(mylist, list2)
[[0, 4, 6, 1, 3, 1, 2], 307]
>>> mylist
[[0, 4, 6, 1, 3, 1, 2], 307]
```

If you need to not modify the original lists, I don't think you're going to really going to get a faster Python implementation of `addres` than the first one you wrote. You might be able to deal with the modification, though, or come up with a somewhat different approach to speed up your code if that's the problem you're facing.

Comment: Hmm this is right, and I see your point. Thanks! I thought pep would only change within the function, my mistake. But... the problem persists if I use newpep = list(pep) then modify and return newpep. So I'm still doing something silly.

Comment: @Roberto `list(pep[0]).extent(res[0])` is not really going to be any faster then `pep[0] + res[0]`

Comment: The problem is that `list(pep)` only does a _shallow_ copy, so that although the lists themselves are different, their first element points to the same object in memory. That is, if you do `newpep = list(pep)`, then `newpep[0] = "something else"` won't change `pep[0]`. But what you're doing is `newpep[0].extend(res[0])`, which changes the list pointed to by both `pep[0]` and `newpep[0]`. (Also, as @cmd points out, there's not really any speed reason to do it this way.)

Answer (score 0):

List are objects in python which are passed by reference.

a=list()

This doesn't mean that a is the list but a is pointing towards a list just created.

In first example, you are using list element and creating a new  list, an another object while in the second one you are modifying the list content itself.

Comment: All values in Python are passed by reference - it's just that it doesn't matter for the immutable types.

Comment: I think this terminology is highly misleading and confusing. Python doesn't pass by reference in the same sense that C-family languages mean—it doesn't pass references to variables, it passes references to values. Which Java explicitly calls "pass by value". So, what _is_ a good name for it? There is no name that answers the question or gives any information without a corresponding explanation.